# How output matrix with a single loop (java)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, matrix

how to output the values ​​of a two-dimensional array in the form of a matrix using single loop (it is forbidden to use the methods of the Arrays class or third-party libraries).

`int[][] data = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7,8},{10}};`

output to the console as a matrix!

1 2 3

4 5 6 7 8

10

Comment: It's fairly easy. You will still need two indices: one for the rows, the other for the column, it's just you update them in a single loop when needed.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. Here is how I would do it.

```
int[][] data = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7,8},{10}};
```

- the `row` and `col` are initialized to `0`.
- the conditional in the loop is for the rows.
- simply print the `row, col`, value and increment the `col`.
- when the col is at the end, print a newline, `col` to `0` and increment the `row`.

```
for (int row = 0, col = 0; row < data.length;) {

    System.out.print(data[row][col++] + " ");
    
    if (col == data[row].length) {
        System.out.println();
        col = 0;
        row++;
    }
}
```

prints

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 7 8 
10
```

The important point is to not increment the `row` until the columns have been printed.

Note:
If it is important to handle empty rows, then place the following code first in the for loop block. This will increment the row and proceed to the next.

```
if (data[row].length == 0) {
    row++;
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {10}};

        int currSubArrayNum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; currSubArrayNum < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(data[currSubArrayNum][i]+" ");
            if (i == data[currSubArrayNum].length - 1) {
                currSubArrayNum++;
                i = -1;
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
```

Comment: @user16320675 he changed question after my answer

Comment: I have not changed the question in this part after your answer)

Comment: it seems working

Answer (score 0):

The most common loops solution is 2 loops (one nested within the other) like so:

```
for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<data[i].length(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", data[i][j]);
    System.out.println();
```

---

**Edit:** If in your desire for 1 loop you mean no inner loop either, the only way that comes up to me is with a loop that runs for each print needed (equal to the length of all the inner arrays combined). Together with a few if statements it goes like so:

```
int[][] data = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7,8},{10}};
int len = data[0].length + data[1].length + data[2].length;
int j = 0;
int h = 0;
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if (h > 0 && h%data[j].length == 0) {
        if (++j == data.length) {break;}
        h=0;
        System.out.println();
     }
     System.out.printf("%d ", data[j][h++%data[j].length]);
}
```

This isn't as elegant, but here is an explaination:

- `i` of the for loop just serves as an indicator for the number of times we want to print. It is not used within the loop conditions or array indices.
- `h` serves as the current number positing within the inner array. When it reaches the length of the inner array, it is reset to zero, and j is increased by 1 (next line).
- `j` is used to indicate a change of an inner array.

Comment: yes, I know that, thanks, but it is very important for me to do it with single loop

Comment: I actually was'nt sure that by saying "using a single loop" you ment no inner loops either. Therefore I intended of posting the first thing that comes to mind and editing after I get the other possibility (no inner loop) out of the way. You guys we're too quick to find my answer before the edit =/ I guess I won't be editing this way anymore. Hope my answer eventually helped in any way though.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can approach this task.

First write down the loops that you would normally use to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
    }
    
    System.out.println();
}
```

Now I say that it is possible to rewrite this code so that there is only a single loop. In order to do this, I will spell down what `for` loops actually do with variables:

```
int i = 0;

while (i < data.length) {
    int j = 0;
    
    while (j < data[i].length) {
        System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
        j++;
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    i++;
}
```

Then I will move the `j` variable out of the outer loop:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (i < data.length) {
    while (j < data[i].length) {
        System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
        j++;
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    i++;
    j = 0;
}
```

And finally I decide that it doesn't actually matter in which loop the code runs as long as it runs under the same conditions on the variables and the loop... loops.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (i < data.length) {
    if (j < data[i].length) {
        System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
        j++;
    } else {
        System.out.println();
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

The last step is not entirely straightforward, but you can't deny the similarity with the previous piece.

Any nested loop can be unrolled with such a technique. You move all the variables outside and replace `while`s with `if`s here and there and voila!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to start with element *[x][y]*, and for each step, print out *(x,y)* and increment *y*. If *y* is out-of-bounds (i.e. equal to or greater than `[x].length`), then increment *x* and reset *y* to 0 (and print out a newline).

```java
void matrix(int[][] array) {
    int dim1 = 0;
    int dim2 = 0;
    while (dim1 < array.length) {
        if (array[dim1].length > 0) {
            System.out.print(array[dim1][dim2]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        dim2++; // Move to next element of sub-array
        
        if (dim2 >= array[dim1].length) {
            dim1++;
            dim2 = 0;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case 2 for loops are allowed
also printing each sub array in next line...

```java
package com.github.manishktiwari.matrix;

/**
 * @author manish
 *
 */
public class PrintMatrixInSingleLoop {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        int[][] mat = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7,8},{10}};
        
        // Dimensions of the matrix
        int N = mat.length;
        int M = getWidth(mat);
        // Function Call
        print2DMatrix(mat, N, M);
    }
    
    private static int getWidth(int[][] mat) {
        int width = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            int[] innerArray = mat[i];
            if (width < innerArray.length) {
                width = innerArray.length;
            }
        }
        return width;
    }

    public static void print2DMatrix(
            int arr[][], int rows, int columns)
        {
     
            // Iterate over the range
            // [0, rows*columns]
            for (int i = 0;
                 i < rows * columns; i++) {
     
                // Find row and column index
                int row = i / columns;
                int col = i % columns;

                try {
                    // Print the element
                    System.out.print(
                        arr[row][col] + " ");
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    System.out.println();
                    i = i + (columns-col-1);
                }
                if (col == columns-1) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

}
```